# request-promise implementation returning `null`

Tags: javascript, request, return, promise, lodash

Any ideas why the value returned from `getBatchedContent` is `null`, given the code sample below?

```
import rp from 'request-promise';
import _ from 'lodash';

function getBatchedContent(size, page) {
  return Promise.resolve(fetchBatchedContent(size, page)); // Getting `null` here.
}

function fetchBatchedContent(size, page) {
  var options = {
    uri: `http://www.example.com/posts?type=vogue-fashion-shows&filter[posts_per_page]=${size}&page=${page}`
  };

  return rp(options)
    .then(function (res) {
      res = JSON.parse(res);
      // res is an array of content objects.
      return _.map(res, function (obj) { // logged value of `_.map()` is correct.
        return transformContent(obj);
      });
    });
}

function transformContent(obj) {
  return {
    id: obj.ID,
    title: obj.title,
    // etc.
  };
}
```

Comment: FYI, `getBatchedContent()` is offering you no additional functionality.  You can just call `fetchBatchedContent()` directly and get the same result.

Comment: If you're talking about the resolved promise value being `null`, then I'd look at your `rp(...).then()` processing to see if it is actually doing what you expect and actually returning the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps add a `.catch(function (error) {debugger;})` to `fetchBatchedContent`. Does it return what you expect?

I'm not sure what you're inputting into `Promise.resolve` that can directly result in `null`? That seems very odd to me, even `Promise.resolve(Promise.reject('foo'))` would return a Promise. (a rejected one).

Comment: Hm...I should clarify that the `null` value is what bubbles up to a json response returned by hapi. I was trying to leave that part of the implementation out of the question, to isolate the cause of the issue. However...adding a `catch` after the `then` in the `return` statement in the body of `fetchBatchedContent` does not result in any caught error.

Comment: So the Promise that `getBatchedContent` returns, resolves to `null`?